# Transform two sided skewed data into normal distribution in R

Tags: r, data-transform

I have some two sided skewed data like the one generated below, and I don't know how to transform it to have a normal distribution or homoscedasticity. I have tried several transformation like log, log+1, exponential, sqrt but nothing seems to work. Any help will be greatly appreciated. TIA.

```
x <- rep(0,20)
y <- rep(1,50)
z <- replicate(50,max(sample(1000,2,replace=TRUE)))
z <- round(z/max(z),2) 
hist(c(x,y,z))
```

[image: data]

Comment: You have 170 data points and only 52 unique values (not only that but 70 of the data points are at the extreme values). You're trying to transform that data to fit a continuous distribution. A sample from a continuous distribution will almost surely be comprised of entirely unique values. You essentially cannot get normality or homoscedasticity from these data.

Comment: I agree its not a good idea to try to turn this into a normal distribution.  It is essentially binary.  Whatever you are trying to do that needs a normally distributed sample - there is probably a better alternative.